# Cakephp copy value from other model to main model

Tags: cakephp

Hi I have model Product and few relative models, output array:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'Product' => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => string '121' (length=3)
          'code' => string '123' (length=3)
      'ProductLanguage' => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => string '5' (length=1)
          'product_id' => string '121' (length=3)
          'name' => string 'abc' (length=3)
      'ProductPrice' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=9)
           'id' => string '1' (length=1)
           'product_id' => string '121' (length=3)
           'type_id' =>  string '7'
           'price' => string '555' (length=3)

          1 => 
            array (size=9)
           'id' => string '2' (length=1)
           'product_id' => string '121' (length=3)
           'type_id' =>  string '8'
           'price' => string '900' (length=3)
   1 =>
...
```

Is it possible copy price from first record (record 0 from ProductPrice>price) to Product? 
I want this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'Product' => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => string '121' (length=3)
          'code' => string '123' (length=3)
          'price' => 555
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in your afterFind callback (In Product Model)

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
        if (isset($val['ProductPrice'][0]['price'])) {
            $results[$key]['Product']['price'] = $val['ProductPrice'][0]['price'];
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Thank You, looks ok in dump have price in Product array but when add sort via price dont working...